# Hangman in Python

Tags: python, optimization, game, python-3.x, hangman

I created this version of Hangman in Python 3.  Does anyone have any tips for optimization or improvement?

```
import random
HANGMAN = (
'''
-------+''',
'''
       +
       |
       |
       |
       |
       |
-------+''',
'''
  -----+
       |
       |
       |
       |
       |
-------+''',
'''
  -----+
  |    |
       |
       |
       |
       |
-------+''',
'''
  -----+
  |    |
  O    |
       |
       |
       |
-------+''',
'''
  -----+
  |    |
  O    |
  |    |
       |
       |
-------+''',
'''
  -----+
  |    |
  O    |
 /|    |
       |
       |
-------+''',
'''
  -----+
  |    |
  O    |
 /|\   |
       |
       |
-------+''',
'''
  -----+
  |    |
  O    |
 /|\   |
 /     |
       |
-------+''',
'''
  -----+
  |    |
  O    |
 /|\   |
 / \   |
       |
-------+''')
MAX = len(HANGMAN) - 1
WORDS = ('jazz', 'buzz', 'hajj', 'fuzz', 'jinx', 'jazzy', 'fuzzy', 'faffs', 'fizzy', 'jiffs', 'jazzed', 'buzzed', 'jazzes', 'faffed', 'fizzed', 'jazzing', 'buzzing', 'jazzier', 'faffing', 'fuzzing')
sizeHangman = 0
word = random.choice(WORDS)
hiddenWord = list('-' * len(word))
lettersGuessed = []
print('\tHANGMAN GAME\n\t\tBy Lewis Cornwall\n')
while sizeHangman < MAX:
    print('This is your hangman:' + HANGMAN[sizeHangman] + '\nThis is the word:\n' + ''.join(hiddenWord) + '\nThese are the letters you\'ve already guessed:\n' + str(lettersGuessed))
    guess = input('Guess a letter: ').lower()
    while guess in lettersGuessed:
        print('You\'ve already guessed that letter!')
        guess = input('Guess a letter: ').lower()
    if guess in word:
        print('Well done, "' + guess + '" is in my word!')
        for i in range(len(word)):
            if guess == word[i]:
                hiddenWord[i] = guess
                if hiddenWord.count('-') == 0:
                    print('Congratulations! My word was ' + word + '!')
                    input('Press <enter> to close.')
                    quit()
    else:
        print('Unfortunately, "' + guess + '" is not in my word.')
        sizeHangman += 1
    lettersGuessed.append(guess)
print('This is your hangman: ' + HANGMAN[sizeHangman] + 'You\'ve been hanged! My word was actually ' + word + '.')
input('Press <enter> to close.')
```

Comment: Not an optimization, but you could load your words from a - possibly encrypted - text file instead of having them in your raw code :)

Answer (score 6):

You can avoid repeating `guess = input('Guess a letter: ').lower()` by changing the inner while loop to:

```
while True:
    guess = input('Guess a letter: ').lower()
    if guess in lettersGuessed:
        print('You\'ve already guessed that letter!')
    else:
        break
```

Instead of `for i in range(len(word))` use:

```
for i, letter in enumerate(word):
```

You could also avoid indexing by `i` altogether by using a list comprehension. I'm not sure if this is as clear in this case, though.

```
hiddenWord = [guess if guess == letter else hidden for letter, hidden in zip(word, hiddenWord)]
```

Instead of `hiddenWord.count('-') == 0` use:

```
'-' not in hiddenWord
```

[The docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#constants-added-by-the-site-module) say `quit()` should not be used in programs. Your `count('-') == 0` check is unnecessarily inside the `for i` loop. If you move it after the loop, you could use `break` to exit the main loop. You could add an `else` clause to the main `with` statement for dealing with the "You've been hanged" case. The main loop becomes:

```
while sizeHangman < MAX:
    print('This is your hangman:' + HANGMAN[sizeHangman] + '\nThis is the word:\n' + ''.join(hiddenWord) + '\nThese are the letters you\'ve already guessed:\n' + str(lettersGuessed))
    while True:
        guess = input('Guess a letter: ').lower()
        if guess in lettersGuessed:
            print('You\'ve already guessed that letter!')
        else:
            break
    if guess in word:
        print('Well done, "' + guess + '" is in my word!')
        for i, letter in enumerate(word):
            if guess == letter:
                hiddenWord[i] = guess
        if '-' not in hiddenWord:
            print('Congratulations! My word was ' + word + '!')
            break
    else:
        print('Unfortunately, "' + guess + '" is not in my word.')
        sizeHangman += 1
    lettersGuessed.append(guess)
else:
    print('This is your hangman: ' + HANGMAN[sizeHangman] + 'You\'ve been hanged! My word was actually ' + word + '.')
input('Press <enter> to close.')
```

Answer (score 3):

Some ideas:

- You might want to make sure that the guess is actually a single letter.
- `lettersGuessed` should be a *set*, so membership tests (`guess in lettersGuessed`) is a constant time operation.
- Similarly, you could store either the (correctly) guessed letters or the letters that still have to be (correctly) guessed in a set. For example:

  ```
  word = random.choice(WORDS)
  requiredGuesses = set(word)
  lettersGuessed = set()

  # then later
  if guess in lettersGuessed:
      print('You already guessed this')
  elif guess in requiredGuesses:
      print('Correct guess!')
      requiredGuesses.remove(guess)
      lettersGuessed.add(guess)
  else:
      print('Incorrect guess')
  ```

  This also makes the test if the whole word was guessed easier:

  ```
  if not requiredGuesses:
      print('You found the word')
  ```
- Instead of keeping a `hiddenWord` which you keep adjusting whenever a correct guess is made, you could just create the hidden output on the fly:

  ```
  print(''.join('-' if l in requiredGuesses else l for l in word))
  ```
- You might want to add a class for this game that encapsulates some of the game logic.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the ability to read words from a txt document. This can be done by:

```
f = open("wordlist.txt", 'w')
word_list.append(f.readlines())
```

this would allow you to have far bigger lists to choose from.